# Navigation from SplitViewController to ViewController

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a view Controller . From the View Controller i am navigating to splitview controller. How to get back from splitview controller to the orignial View Controller?

Comment: How you are showing the SplitViewcontroller?

Comment: I have a button in view controller. Through segue I am navigating to split view controller. The split view controller has a tableview controller and a plus button to add the data. Click on any row in the splitview controller opens the data in another controller.